# Why use fork in a simple program?

Tags: unix, fork

I'm learning the basics of fork(). One of the programs I've been asked to work has a few functions that are to be run 1000 times. And then again, except in a forked process presumably because it's faster.

My question is why would it be faster to run simple functions (that create arrays, linked lists, and perform system calls) in a forked process since doesn't the fork simply make a full copy of the original program?

Answer (score 3):

There's generally no reason for a parent to fork a single child to do that sort of work, but if a parent forks *multiple* children, then that work can be distributed across multiple processors, or the multiple units of work can at least be scheduled to make optimal use of one processor is the forked children ever need to wait on I/O, or for a long-running system call.

Nowadays threads are more often used for this sort of thing, as threads use less resources than new processes -- but it still makes a good learning exercise.